# Google Cloud Django Postgres: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: django, database, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've deployed a Django project to Google App Engine Flexible Environment and using postgress for database connection.

I followed this https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

I've successfully setup it on my local machine but when I deploy on cloud I'm getting following error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here is my database setup in my `settings.py`

```
 DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME',
            'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
            'USER': 'DB_USERNAME',
            'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

when I start server in local db:
`./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="PROJECT_NAME:REGION:INSTANCE_NAME"=tcp:5432`

I get this :
`Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432 for PROJECT_NAME:REGION:INSTANCE_NAME"=tcp:5432`

and when try on local i tried like this:

```
 DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME',
            'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
            'USER': 'DB_USERNAME',
            'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
            'PORT': '5432',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1'
        }
```

This works on my local computer and I can access DB. but when I remove `'HOST': '127.0.0.1'` for deployment. after deployment I'm getting `connection refused error`

my `app.yaml` file -

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT website.wsgi

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: ciento-338906:us-east1:ciento-instance

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.7

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
```

Comment: What's your app engine configuration? Where is deployed your database?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thank you for responding. I created a new Postgress instance in Cloud SQL. I'm editing the question with app.yaml file. If you can get any idea from it.

Comment: You must use the unix socket on App Engine, that is not the case locally. You aren't in the exact same configuration. I'm not a django expert. I have doubt on the engine and its support of unix socket. I found a tutorial here on Cloud Run, but if you know django, you will understand it better than me. https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run